# Django - Passing argument through href for URL dispatcher?

Tags: python, django

So I am working on a website where at some point I do a search and list a list of textbooks on the page. From there I want the user to be able to click on a textbook and each textbook will have it's own details page. I have been trying to work with Django's URL dispatcher but I am having difficulties. Code and description below.

results.html

```
<table class="table">
    {% for items in results %}
    <tr><td>{{items.textbook_name}}</td><td>{{items.class_name}}</td><td>{{items.author}}</td><td>{{items.isbn}}</td><td><a href = "{% url 'textchange:textbook' %}?text_name={{items.textbook_name}}">></a></td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Views.py

```
def textbook(request, text_name):
    return render_to_response(
        'textchange/textbook.html',
        locals(),
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
        )
```

Urls.py

```
    url(r'^results/(?P<text_name>\w+)/$', views.textbook, name="textbook"),
```

From my understanding I thought I was passing the items.textbook_name as text_name to urls from the html and then views would be called with text_name as an argument but it is not working. I might be a little backwards here. I need the textbook_name from the textbook the user clicks on so on the details page I can display all it's information from the database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick explanation.

Let's say that your url doesn't need text_name parameter, so that:

```
{% url 'textchange:textbook' %}?text_name={{items.textbook_name}}
```

will result in:

```
/results/?text_name=some-name
```

`text_name` won't get passed to url tag, it was simply glued on the end of url.

To pass text_name into url, and build proper url, you should do that:

```
{% url 'textchange:textbook' text_name=items.textbook_name %}
```

and it will result in url:

```
/results/some-name/
```

Comment: OK, that fixed a small bit. Now will text_name be able to be used as a parameter for my view? EDIT: my regex was wrong, working now. Thanks!